Error when trying to get an action from a loaded Tensorflow Policy
I get this error when trying to get an action from a Tensorflow policy that I previously trained:
ValueError: Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
  Positional arguments (2 total):
    * TimeStep(
{'step_type': <tf.Tensor 'time_step:0' shape=() dtype=int32>,
 'reward': <tf.Tensor 'time_step_1:0' shape=() dtype=float32>,
 'discount': <tf.Tensor 'time_step_2:0' shape=() dtype=float32>,
 'observation': <tf.Tensor 'time_step_3:0' shape=(1, 4) dtype=float32>})
    * ()
  Keyword arguments: {}

 Expected these arguments to match one of the following 2 option(s):

Option 1:
  Positional arguments (2 total):
    * TimeStep(step_type=TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name='step_type'), reward=TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name='reward'), discount=TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name='discount'), observation=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 4), dtype=tf.float32, name='observation'))
    * ()
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 2:
  Positional arguments (2 total):
    * TimeStep(step_type=TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name='time_step_step_type'), reward=TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name='time_step_reward'), discount=TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name='time_step_discount'), observation=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 4), dtype=tf.float32, name='time_step_observation'))
    * ()
  Keyword arguments: {}

This is the code that I'm using:
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tf_agents.trajectories import time_step as ts
import os
import tempfile

# Temporary directory for the policy
tempdir = os.getenv("TEST_TMPDIR", tempfile.gettempdir())
policy_dir = os.path.join(tempdir, 'policy')

# Load the saved policy
saved_policy = tf.saved_model.load(policy_dir)

# Define state and ensure it has a batch dimension (add an extra dimension)
state = np.array([[0, 0.5, 1, 0]], dtype=np.float32)  # Shape (1, 4)

# Create a TimeStep from the state
time_step = ts.restart(state)

# Get the action from the policy
action = saved_policy.action(time_step)

print(action)

I don't understand why this doesn't work, as the input the policy recieved seems to match the expected input, at least to my eye
